# Conditionally bind a function in Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

```
<div data-bind="foreach: passengers">                       
<a href="#" data-bind='style: { color: isOwner  ? "orange" : "darkgreen" }, 
text: person_username, click: function() { $root.removePassenger($data, $parent); } '>
```

Say I have a template like this.  The click function should only be bound if isOwner is true.  Is there a simple/easy way to do this?  I'm guessing I could break out the full jquery templating and get something done, but I'd like to know a more elegant solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for -- handle a click event only when some property is set -- is application logic. Application logic does not belong in the view. It belongs in the view model.

Sure, you *could* do something like:

```
click: function() { if ($data.isOwner) $root.removePassenger($data, $parent); }
```

But, again, that's putting logic in your view, which is frowned upon from a separation-of-concerns and debugging point of view, and it uglifies your HTML.

I'd suggest doing it like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: passengers">                       
   <a href="#" data-bind='style: { color: isOwner  ? "orange" : "darkgreen" }, 
      text: person_username, click: function() { $root.removePassengerIfApplicable($data, $parent);"</a>
</div>
```

And your JavaScript:

```
function removePassengerIfApplicable(passenger, parent) {
    if (passenger.isOwner) {
        removePassenger(passenger, parent);
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

It wasn't clear from your post that you didn't want to show a link if isOwner = false. Here's some updated code for you:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: passengers">  
   <div data-bind="if: isOwner">                     
      <a href="#" style="color: orange" 
      text: person_username, click: function() { $root.removePassenger($data, $parent); }"</a>
   </div>
   <div data-bind="if !isOwner()">
      <span style="color: darkgreen" data-bind="text: person_username"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

The above code shows a link if isOwner, and a plain text span if not.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but even though it has application logic there is view logic involved, being that I don't want the name to show up as a link if they can't do anything anyway.  I guess I could just disable it.

Comment: Yes exactly.  Would just disabling it be the best bet?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer so that a plain text span is shown if isOwner = false.